# Extract elements from a list using index from another list using R

Tags: r, list, select

I have two lists in R

1) `a<-as.list(c(2,4,6,10))`

```
 int : 2
 int : 4
 int : 6
 int : 10
```

2) `b<-as.list(c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m"))`

```
 chr : "a"
 chr : "b"
 chr : "c"
 chr : "d"
 chr : "e"
 chr : "f"
 chr : "g"
 chr : "h"
 chr : "i"
 chr : "j"
 chr : "k"
 chr : "l"
 chr : "m"
```

And I need an output with the intervals from list one 2:4, 6:10

```
 b c d f g h i j
```

Comment: Please provide the actual structure of these examples as data that we can copy. You can paste the results of `dput` if it makes it easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this

```
a <- list(2,4,6,10)
b <- lapply(1:13,function(x) letters[x])
M <- matrix(unlist(a),byrow = T,ncol=2)
unlist(b)[unlist(mapply(seq,M[,1],M[,2]))]
```

---

Thanks to @Psidom's comment, We can use

```
b[unlist(Map(seq, a[c(T, F)], a[c(F, T)]))]
```

instead of

```
M <- matrix(unlist(a),byrow = T,ncol=2)
unlist(b)[unlist(mapply(seq,M[,1],M[,2]))]
```

Comment: Another way to get around building a matrix would be `b[unlist(Map(seq, a[c(T, F)], a[c(F, T)]))]`.